# Understanding Html.ActionLink(..., ..., ...) syntax in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm doing a tutorial on MVC 3 and I stumbled upon the helper @Html.ActionLink(genre.Name, "Browse", new {genre = genre.Name}).

Now I understand what the values do and that the third value is a route parameter value but this is the first time I'm seeing this kind of syntax which is really bugging me for some reason.

What I mean exactly is **new {genre = genre.Name}**. I've come to understand that "new" precedes object/type declaration, however, this time it's simply the "new" keyword and the curly brackets. How exactly is this processed?

Comment: i am thinking more of instantiating the object 'genre' as var genre = new genre.Name; but i may be wrong !!

Comment: @Andrew If any of the replies satisfies you please mark it as answer. Do that for your old questions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `new { prop = val }` creates an **anonymous type**.  It's essentially the same as creating an instance of a class, except you're declaring the class and the instance all in one shot.  Some people think that anonymous types are not statically typed or are not type safe.  This isn't true.  The types of the properties are inferred from the values they are assigned.  This construction is used frequently in MVC and in linq.

Note that this syntax is not specific to MVC.  You can use it anywhere it's convenient.  I make a fair amount of use of anonymous types in day-to-day coding.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.. the first parameter is the link you want to display, so `genre.Name` can corresponds to **Rock**. The second argument is the `action`, the third argument your **Controller** class. The last parameter is the **route values** in the form of an anonymous object (an object you will never use again, the MVC engine uses the anonymous object in this case). 
So your `action`(method) takes a `string` argument.

For example: 
"Home" is the link the user sees (the first argument), Home (the second argument) is the `action` (method) to your `Controller` class, and it takes a `string` argument.

```
class HomeController
{
  public ActionResult GenreAction(string genre)
  {

  }
}
```

When a request is made, it becomes `Home/GenreAction/genre`

Answer (score 0):

It's a C# language feature called [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), introduced with C# 3.5 if I'm not mistaken.